# Две формы обратной связи в Netcat

Tags: php, формы, компоненты, netcat

Настроил форму обратной связи в Netcat, но задача стоит сделать 2 формы на одной странице. Создал под каждую свой шаблон но столкнулся с проблемой, что выбранные поля для любой формы будут присваиваться всем формам на странице. Как сделать две разные формы обратной связи с разными полями на одной странице?
[image: crhbyijn]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Преданная служба поддержки помогла, поэтому, на случай если возникнет такая же диллема копирую ответ сюда:

Компонент, который показан на скриншоте, предназначен для лендинг-страниц. Для удобства настройки на таких страницах все формы обратной связи («заявок») настраиваются одновременно: обычно лендинг-страница является призывом к одному действию.

Можно изменить это поведение, немного изменив сам компонент, либо создав дополнительный шаблон для него.

Смысл изменений в шаблоне компонента состоит в передаче в шаблоне компонента «Формы» в метод nc_requests::make_form() типа формы (вторым аргументом).

Для удобной настройки можно добавить у шаблона компонента новую пользовательскую настройку:
· название: form_type
· описание: тип формы
· тип: строка (или список, если у вас заранее известный набор форм)
Тогда в шаблоне суффиксе списка надо заменить:
Код:

```
echo nc_requests::make_form($cc);
```

на:
Код:

```
echo nc_requests::make_form($cc, $cc_settings['form_type']);
```

В настройках блока появится поле «Тип формы», где можно указать значение вида "feedback_form", "order_form" и т. п. Формы одного типа будут в режиме редактирования настраиваться на странице независимо (изменения наборов полей при этом будут касаться всех форм указанного типа).
Если тип формы не указан, будет показана форма «по умолчанию» — как в стандартном шаблоне компонента.